# conflict name affects folder and php file

Tags: php, html, naming-conventions

in my web site folder I have a folder named `area-nursing` containing other php file and a php file named `area_nursing.php`. When I transform through `.htaccess` area_nursing.php to `area-nursing` I got a conflict name between php file and folder name.How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your best bet is to just rename the file. I'm not sure what you are doing in your .htaccess file but I'm assuming you are rewriting the URL without the .php extension.